# Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that if $L' \neq L$ then $L$ has infinitely many non-isomorphic 1-dimensional modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that if $L' \neq L$ then $L$ has infinitely many non-isomorphic 1-dimensional modules.

I have already shown that if $\gamma: L \rightarrow gl(1,F)$ is a one dimensional representation then $\gamma(L')=0$. I have also showed that any representation of $\frac{L}{L'}$ can be seen as a representation of $L$ on which $L'$ acts trivially...

What is the most natural way to define a representation $\gamma: \frac{L}{L'} \rightarrow gl(1,F)$? How do I get inifitely many non-isomorphic of them?? Just sending all of $\frac{L}{L'}$ to a fixed complex number or something?? Help and detailed answers appreciated!

Comment: How you have showed that any representation of $L/L′$
 can be seen as a representation of $L$
 on which $L′$
 acts trivially...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a linear form  $\lambda\in L^*$ on $L$ the map $\rho_{\lambda} : L\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ with $x\mapsto \lambda(x)$ is a representation if and only if $\lambda$ vanishes on $L'=[L,L]$.
This $1$-dimensional representation then is denoted by $k_{\lambda}$.
So the map $\lambda\rightarrow k_{\lambda}$ induces
a bijection of $(L/L')^*$  and the isomorphism classes of all $1$-dimensional representations of $L$.

So if $L'\neq L$, the space $(L/L')^*$ has infinitely many elements, over an infinite field $k$.

Comment: So if $\lambda$ doesn't vanish on $L'$, then $([p_{\lambda}(x),p_{\lambda}(y)])=\lambda(x)\lambda(y)-\lambda(y)\lambda(x)=0$ but $p_{\lambda}([x,y])=\lambda([x,y]) \neq 0$??? Can you help me understand why $\lambda([x,y]) \neq 0$? Also, why is it obvious that all one dimensional representations are of this form?

Comment: Can I help you with $\lambda([x,y])\neq 0$ if $\lambda$ doesn't vanish on $L'$? Yes, by definition $L'=[L,L]$.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit slow! Can you help me to understand why different $\lambda$ do not give isomorphic representations?